# Rest API Response Error Code for when a related resource has a blocked state

Tags: rest, api

Which 400-level response code is most appropriate when a user that has permission to POST a target resource, but one of the dependent resources' status causes the target resource not to be created.

Example:

```
Entity1
  id: 'A',
  status: 'BLOCKED'

Entity2:
  id: 'B'

LinkEntity:
   entity1Id: 'A'
   entity2Id: 'B'

Result when POSTing LinkedEntity: 'Error: Cannot link to Entity1 because it is BLOCKED'
```

*Which Response Code is best to use in this case?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [409 (Conflict)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code indicates that the request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target resource.

Comment: It is the state of a non-target resource that is conflicting.

Comment: I agree that this is the best of the available response codes because the state of the data is in conflict, which is a better indicator than saying that resource or endpoint is forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a permission-related issue. For this case `403 Forbidden` is probably best.

Comment: even though the user has been granted permission to POST to this endpoint?

Comment: I think that depends a bit on your definition of permission. Clearly in this case the user was not permitted to do something. I would agree with the other answer that 409 Might also be good depending on what 'blocked' means.